# log of everything typed via input('foo') python

Tags: python, text

I want to log what is typed in my program (home assistant) to go to a sort of `file/directory/log` of what is typed.

I only want to log it when I call `foo = input('::')` otherwise, like just random typing that has nothing to do with the program what so ever.

I have looked into this question with google and it is all about defining you own functions and that stuff.

I would like to end up with something like this: `Joe/chat/day/good` with each time 'Joe' is typed in, start a new `file/directory/log` or whatever you want to call it.

Should I make a function of input, or anything else?

Comment: Why do you need such a complicated folder system? This will log `foo` to log.txt file: `with open('log.txt', 'a') as file: <newline and indent> file.write(foo)` if you use that after the `input` line

Comment: The problem with that is that it would take very long to do that. I have at least 50 (or more) . Should I just def input as a function and put your suggestion in there? Or is that messy os something?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your problem is to make your own input.

```
import os

logdir = os.getcwd() # Path to the log directory
activation = ["joe", "Joe"] # Start new log when a word is first in input
thelog = open(os.path.join(logdir, "0 - startlog.log"), "wb")
lognum = 0

_input = input # Save original input()
def input (prompt):
    global thelog, lognum
    i = _input(prompt)
    check = i.split(None, 1) # Split by first word and the rest of sentence
    if not check or not check[0] in activation:
        thelog.write(b"")
        return i
    # Now change the log:
    thelog.close()
    lognum += 1
    thelog = open(os.path.join(logdir, ("%i - " % lognum)+check[0]+".log"), "wb")
    thelog.writeline(i)
    return i
```

Or something similar.

After this code, you use input() as usual, but anything entered also goes into a file.
Entries are written in lines. Empty inputs will reflect as empty lines.
When activation word is first in the entered line a new log is started in a new file.
The files are numbered 0,1,2,... and an activation word follows in their name. I understood you wish to achieve something like that.

If you want to store everything user types ever, then you make a wrapper around sys.stdin whose read() method reads from sys.**stdin**, then writes a result to the log, and then returns the result.
And you swap sys.stdin with the wrapper object.

Comment: Ow, BTW, don't forget to close() the last log[ thelog.close() ] before your program exits. You may even want to use atexit module to register thelog.close() to be called upon programs clean termination automatically.

Comment: There is an error with `if not checkor not check[0] in activation:` At `check[0]` It is a syntax error. Do I need an `and` or `or` in there somewhere?